# Cloudify: Upgrade of agents in application hosts

Tags: cloudify

Currently I am using cloudify 3.3.1. I wish to upgrade to 3.4. After upgrade the agents in the cloudify manager will be of upgraded version. How the agents in the application hosts will get upgraded? or If the agents in the cloudify manager (latest version) and the agents (older version) will still work good?in application hosts

Answer (score 1):

For upgrading from 3.3.1 to 3.4

- You have to create a snapshot of the
  3.3.1 manager
- Restore it on an already bootstrapped 3.4 manager.
- After deploying the new manager you should also install the new
  agents on running deployments as described in:
  http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.0/workflows/built-in-workflows/#the-install-new-agents-workflow

The old agents will be replaced with new ones.